# Submitting a value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been pulling my hair out with this one, although I'm certain the solution is embarrassingly simple! I have developed a pull-down menu that requires a selection before presenting more choices, based on the initial selection. It works fine.

However, I need to have jQuery submit the value of the option chosen without a submit button present. So, basically, when  a user selects a fruit size, the user is taken to the relevant page in the option value. I cant figure it out! Heres my code:

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#fruit').change(function()
    {
        var val = $('#fruit').val();
        $('.fruitSubSelect').hide();
        if(val)
        {
        $('#fruit'+val).show();
        $('#noFruit').hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

CSS to hide size select:

```
<style type="text/css">
.fruitSubSelect {display: none;}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="nothing">
<select id="fruit">
<option value="">Choose Fruit</option>
<option>Apple</option>
<option>Orange</option>
</select>
<select id="fruitApple" class="fruitSubSelect">
<option value="">Choose Size</option>
<option value="http://www.mysite.com/big-apple.html">Big Apple</option>
<option value="http://www.mysite.com/small-apple.html">Small Apple</option>
</select>
<select id="fruitOrange" class="fruitSubSelect">
<option value="">Choose Size</option>
<option value="http://www.mysite.com/big-orange.html">Big Orange</option>
<option value="http://www.mysite.com/small-orange.html">Small Orange</option>
</select>
<select id="noFruit">
<option value="">Choose A Fruit First</option>
<option value="">Please Select Fruit First</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Would appreciate any help! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
$(".fruitSubSelect").change(function(){
   window.location.href = this.value;
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/bWUnR/

This will get the selected value of the dropdown and set the window location to it (so the page will go to it).

Answer (score 2):

the addition of this into your jquery alert's the selected option's URL:

```
$('.fruitSubSelect').change(function(){
    alert($(':selected',$(this)).val());
});
```

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/274Gv/

Answer (score 0):

With dropdowns, do not use .val(). :selected is what you're looking for. http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/